# how to make next and previous button in android

Tags: android

I am working on app, in which I want to move images with the help of next and previous button. As I run this, app starts but doesn't show any thing.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
public  class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ViewFlipper vf;
    Button b1;
    Button b2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         vf = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.vf);
         b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
         b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2); 

         b1.setOnClickListener(this);
         b2.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == b1) {

        vf.showNext();
    }

    else if (v == b2) {

        vf.showPrevious();

    }

}

}
```

Comment: did you bind data to the viewflipper??from xml or java??

Comment: refer here...https://android-coffee.com/slideshow-next-prev-buttons-android-studio/